# Ionic splash not generating full screen image

Tags: ionic-framework

There is not much about splash screen for ionic. According to documentation it should be very simple.
What I did then was to download the psd-file from here:

```
http://code.ionicframework.com/resources/splash.psd
```

Then I created my artwork which is 1200X1200 pixels. I copied the artwork and put it in the middle of the psd-file.

After that, I just run the command to generate the splash screens for the various devices (testing ios right now).

When I start the app, the splash screen doesn't cover all the screen. It is centered vertically and above and below there are a lot of empty pixels. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in which device are you checking for iOS, also did you return anything for orientation or for splash in config.xml?

Comment: I got the same problem both with simulator and real device. I didn't touch config.xml, but seems it only allows portrait (this is the way i want it to be). I will try to follow instructions posted by @Ray

Comment: if your issue is not yet solved please check you have all the splash images listed in the config.xml for ex: `<splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" height="1334" width="750"/>` this

Answer (score 2):

Actually ionic Splash screen pixels should be **2208pixels**.

Then you have to Replace your splash screen in your resources file with your splash screen.

Then run  `ionic resources --splash` command in your terminal to load your splash screen and that should do the trick.

To know more about ionic-splash look here [ionic-doc](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/icon-splashscreen.html).

Comment: Sorry. But the splash screen IS 2208 pixels. The artwork is 1200x1200 and is centered within the splash screen. This is what I understood when reading the docs. Is that wrong?

Comment: if you are using photoshop, create a new file 2208x2208 transparent back. then copy paste your artwork,add a new layer on bottom and fill it with background color that best fits the contrast of your artwork (considering it just an icon like facebook or any other app). If your artwork is detailed image then ask your graphic designer mto make you a new one 2208x2208